# What does a recursive min s,t-cut optimize?

Tags: optimization, dag, minimum-cuts

Consider the following algorithm sketch:

Given an edge-weighted directed acyclic graph $G = (V, E, w : E \to \mathbb{N})$, adjoin a temporary source $s$ and sink $t$ to get $G' = (V', E', w')$. $G'$ should have edges pointing from $s$ to all nodes in $G$ that have an empty set of in-neighbors, and edges pointing from all nodes in $G$ that have an empty set of out-neighbors to $t$. Edges should not be added between completely disconnected nodes (ones with no out- or in-neighbors) and $s$ or $t$. These edges should have weight $1 + \sum_{e \in E} w(e)$ (or any number much greater than the existing weights, the specific number doesn't matter much). Then, run any minimum s,t-cut algorithm on $G'$ to produce two sets $X, Y \subseteq V$ where $s \in X$ and $t \in Y$. Return $(X', Y') = (X - \{s\}, Y - \{t\})$.

Now given any edge-weighted DAG and a stopping condition, we can run this algorithm recursively, e.g.: by calling this on the subgraph induced by $X'$ and the subgraph induced by $Y'$. The stopping condition decides whether a set is worth continuing to split. The result of this recursive algorithm is a set of sets of nodes.

There's some ambiguity in this description since it's unspecified which side of the partition the minimum s,t-cut should put the completely disconnected nodes in. Feel free to make whatever assumptions you want about this behavior.

Suppose that our stopping condition is "each subgraph should contain no edges". This results in a set of anticliques in $G$. Is this set the answer to some optimization problem? Is this algorithm a greedy approximation of any optimization problem?

Comment: Can you please give some context? What's the motivation for the question?

Comment: @Dmitry I'm writing an algorithm where I want to convert a directed acyclic graph into a path graph such that cuts in the path graph correspond to cuts in the DAG, while giving up as little as possible (since, e.g.: I have an algorithm to do a multiway-min-cut-with-extra-constraints on the path graph). This recursive min-cut seems like a good way to do that, but I'm left wondering -- what problem exactly is this solving?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but It reminds me of hierarchical clustering objectives: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05043, https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/hash/d8d31bd778da8bdd536187c36e48892b-Abstract.html. The idea is that edges cut at the top levels tend to have greater multipliers (in the objective function) compared with edges cut at the bottom levels.